# Security tab missing on Windows 7 VM

Tags: windows-7, vmware-fusion

I am trying to get a .NET website running.

The problem I am getting can be resolved by setting the security on the folder that the site is running from, but I do not have a security tab.

I am running Windows 7 in a VM on OS X.

Comment: You're trying to run a .NET website from a Windows 7 machine? Shouldn't you be using Windows Server?

Comment: I am taking over development of a site from another developer. The site does not run locally from the latest web express install.

Answer (score 1):

Ok fixed, problem was that the folder name was over 9 characters and for what ever reason that causes and error. Nothing to do with security permissions on folder.

Comment: Consider marking this answer as *"accepted"* by clicking the checkmark to the left of the question. For more info on accepting answers, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)